# media query doesn't work without screen

Tags: css, less, media-queries, media

I have a problem when I use media query in css3: without `screen`, meida query doesn't work.

Here is code:

```
.side-menu {
    position: fixed;
    ...
    display: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    @media screen and (min-width: @screen-xs) {
        display: block;
    }
    @media and (min-width: @screen-md) {
        right: 8.1%;
    }
}
```

Problem: the first media query works and the seconds doesn't. If I remove the screen and the first doesn't work either.

SO, could anyone help me?

Comment: Is this running through a preprocessor like SASS or LESS?

Comment: Yes, it's Less used.

Comment: Any chance you could include the compiled CSS as well?

Comment: I ckecked for times and finally find that I didn't remove `and` when I remove `screen`. This is a stupid fault. I'll close the question. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: It's always those little things :)

Comment: @creeper I noticed this question is still open. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `and` in this line:

```
@media and (min-width: @screen-md)
```

To become:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md)
```